# Labelling scatter data points

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, surface

I have a surface graph and on it I have plotted some points. Now I want to label each of these points. I used the following code.

```
name={'point1','point2','point3','point4','point5'}
co=[0 0 0];
scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],co,'filled');
c=cellstr(name);
dx = 0.1; dy = 0.1;
dz=0.1;
text(X+dx, Y+dy,Z+dz, c);
```

But the label data are **not clear**.
[image]

What can I do to make these labels clear?

---

Still after changing as   `'Color', 'black', 'FontSize', 14)`
 the labels are displayed as

[image]
  Still they are not clear.

Comment: `text(..., 'Color', 'white', 'FontSize', 14);` change `white` and `14` as desired.

Comment: @IKavanagh I changed as `'Color', 'black', 'FontSize', 14`. But still the labels are not clear. I included the new plot in the post

Comment: I think both answers do not address the full problem: namely that the text appears intertwined with the plot. Regardless of a `background`-property, this will happen. My suggestion would be to lift the textlabels above the plot manually, i.e. lowering the `x` and `y` coordinates and increasing the `z` one in this view. You do have to know the view of your plot before hand though, but at least you can get the text on top of your graph.

Comment: @Adriaan Yes I let dz=0.2; and now it works. Thank you. But then the label looks a little too away from the point.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks. got it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make text appear *above*  the surface, you need to change the coordinates of the `text` itself. This is slightly complicated and requires a bit of visual confirmation, but it would look something like this:

[image]

Where I used the following code:

```
data = rand(5,3);
X=data(:,1);
Y=data(:,2);
Z=data(:,3);
figure;scatter3(X,Y,Z)
hold on
name={'point1','point2','point3','point4','point5'}
c=cellstr(name);
dx = -0.1; dy = -0.1;
dz=0.2;
text(X+dx, Y+dy,Z+dz, c);
```

You will have to visually confirm the location of the text in relation to the plot, and change `dx`, `dy` and `dz` accordingly. Note though that as you rotate the plot text might well go behind the surface.

Text properties, such as `background` and `FontWeight` as mentioned in the other answers can help to make your text readable on your graph, in addition to this way of bringing text to the front.

Answer (score 5):

ok now I got it:
use `set(gca,'SortMethod','childorder')`
I added an example below

```
    name={'<-point1','<-point2','<-point3','<-point4','<-point5'};
    co=[0 0 0];
    X  = repmat([1:10],1,10);
    Y  = sort(repmat([1:10],1,10));
    Z = X.*Y;

    X2 = repmat([1:10],10,1);
    Y2 = X2';
    Z2 = X2.*Y2;

    figure
    hold on 
    surf(X2,Y2,Z2);
    set(gca,'View',[-45 30])
    scatter3(X,Y,Z,[],co,'filled');

    c=cellstr(name);
    dx = 0.3; dy = -0.2;
    dz=0.1;
    %text(X(51:55)+dx, Y(51:55)+dy,Z(51:55)+dz, c,'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1]);
    text(X(51:55)+dx, Y(51:55)+dy,Z(51:55)+dz, c,'Color','white','Fontweight','bold');    
    scatter3(X(51:55),Y(51:55),Z(51:55),[],ones(5,3),'filled','MarkerEdgeColor','k');
    set(gca,'SortMethod','childorder')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the generic version of my manual work-around, cool! Might I suggest though that you remove the `close` and `clear` statements, since people copying this code in the middle of their own program might run into problems. Also: Upload the figure, because figures look nice and get you upvotes ;)

Comment: @ Adriaan: deleted it. I always like stand alone code versions but of course a clear all in the middle of the code is not helpful ;)

Comment: It's a hard to see which points each tag relates to. Now that you have this white background, might I suggest coloring the font of the label and the color of the point with some random color each time?

Comment: @Dev-iL right: I added a second version without background

Comment: @horseshoe This other version does look nice, however if you were trying to address the problem I mentioned, this is not what I had in mind... As it is still difficult (impossible?) to know which point the label relates to. I meant maybe you should create another, `scatter` plot on top of the surface with the points that have labels colored for example in white/red.

Answer (score 3):

Use the background property of the text command:

```
text(0,1,'Hi the first point','background',[1 230/255 230/255]);
```

[image]

Comment: I have done `h=text(X+dx, Y+dy,Z+dz, c,'Color', 'black', 'FontSize', 14,'background',[1 230/255 230/255],'BackgroundColor',[1 1 1],'FontWeight','bold');
uistack(h, 'top')`  but still the points are displayed as http://snag.gy/klWNR.jpg    If I remove the surface graph then the labels are displayed correctly.